# How to securely setup a DVR for remote viewing

Tags: surveillance, cctv

I can't find any guides or helpful forums on how to securely setup a DVR system for remote video surveillance. And by setup I mean - what kind of DVR and how to setup/connect the system to the Internet so it has a good level of security?

From what I've read many DVR's have some sort of default passwords that allow hackers/bots that scan the network to gain almost instant access, yet I didn't find any solutions to this problem - are all DVR's really that vulnerable? Then I've stumbled upon some vague advice on setting up VPN for connecting to the DVR, which again I couldn't understand.

Can you provide advice? Is there a place that provides advice on this subject? If I go with a PC-based DVR solution - is it the same as setting up a PC for remote access, or the DVR card/software would still add the vulnerability of default passwords?

Comment: there are tons of resources on how to set up VPNs - they just might not be VPN-specific, because they do not need to be

Comment: if there are known default credentials, then you should be able to search for  the DVR model you want and see if they are published

Comment: big tip - don't host the DVR in your home network - set it up in a segregated network

Comment: All kinds of tips - that's great and thanks for that! But is there a complete guide on how to setup the whole thing?